# Does the series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{3}{(-2)^k}$ converge? If so, find the sum.

Tags: calculus

Does the series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{3}{(-2)^k}$ converge? If so, find the sum.
Is this just a geometric series?

Comment: Yes. It is a geometric series

Comment: Think $3\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-\frac{1}{2})^k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{3}{(-2)^k}=3\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^k
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k\ge0}\dfrac1{(-2)^k}=\dfrac 1{1-(-\dfrac 12)}=\dfrac 23$.

So, $\sum_{k\ge2}\dfrac 3{(-2^k)}=3(\dfrac 23-(1-\dfrac 12))=\dfrac 12$.